# Django 2.1/PostgreSQL - can I prevent deleting model objects?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

There were some questions in the past about this but as `Django` grows, there are many new database functions.

I'm looking for a way to prevent `model` to be deleted from anywhere by anyone.

I have a model `Product` and I don't want product to be deleted from database ever.

I understand that overriding `delete` is sometimes a good way but I would like to do it on `database` level so there is no chance to delete it from `shell_plus` or any other source.

In `Postgres`, I think, there is a way:

```
CREATE RULE product_del_protect AS ON DELETE TO product DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

But I would like to do it through `Django` so every migrated database will be affected.

There may be a way to do that in `model` or custom `migration`.

And better would be to raise an error.

Comment: I don't think a native django solution exists for this, but you can always use raw sql: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/

Comment: @Stargazer Yes I think combining raw query and migrations.RunPython would be the best way.

Comment: I agree. Just write a migration for that https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/howto/writing-migrations/